# How to set the 1st week day to Monday in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I built an app totally based in dates. Now the client really wants to make Monday as the 1st day of week and I've plenty of calendar views, diary view, log views, calculations, etc based in dates and always considering Sunday as first day of week because it's Javascript default. It's the day zero when you call the GetDay() function of the Date object.

Is there something I can do to set the 1st day of week as Monday ?

ty !

Comment: Consider wrapping the date with your own "class".

Comment: Are you using MomentJs, if not, I would highly advise you do, because this is what moment was built for

Comment: Using just Angular 2, @CallumLinington ! But indeed I will research about this ! at least for curiosity ! ty

Comment: Angular is a framework, moment is a library..... would be silly not to use libraries to help you solve your problems. Will save you a lot of time ;)

Comment: Yes, I know - Just trying to expose a bit my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you want monday as first day you can do this:

> const dayIndex = defaultDayIndex === 0 ? 6 : defaultDayIndex-1;

```
const myDate = new Date('2021-12-07');

const defaultDayIndex = myDate.getDay();
// make monday first day of the week and sunday the last day
// monday will be index 0, and sunday will be index 6
const dayIndex = defaultDayIndex === 0 ? 6 : defaultDayIndex-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const weekMap = {
    1: 0, // → monday
    2: 1, // → tuesday
    3: 2, // → wednesday
    4: 3, // → thursday
    5: 4, // → friday
    6: 5, // → saturday
    0: 6, // → sunday
};

console.log(weekMap[(new Date()).getDay()]);
```

Comment: Previous answer is basically the same. And a comment there about using a library like date-fns, moment, etc.. is more than valid

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.